# Features of Jquery Data Table is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, spring-mvc

I am trying to use dataTable with CDN however the view is looking fine my table is looking like a DataTable but its functionalities are not working like searching sorting, etc.

**here is my JSP file code.**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Student List</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>The List of Students IS :</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="button" value="Add New Student"
                onclick="addStudentForm()">
        </div>

        <div id="addStudentForm"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <table id="dataTable" class="">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student Name</th>
                        <th>Student Course</th>
                        <th>Student Father</th>
                        <th>Student Address</th>
                        <th>Student Email</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <c:forEach var="tempStudent" items="${theStudent}">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>${tempStudent.name }</td>
                            <td>${tempStudent.course }</td>
                            <td>${tempStudent.fatherName }</td>
                            <td>${tempStudent.address }</td>
                            <td>${tempStudent.email }</td>
                            <td><a>Update</a>| <a>Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dataTable').dataTable();
});
 </script>


</html>
```

This is the code I have used and I have checked there are no issues on the console as well but I am not getting why it is not working for me please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define parameters specific to functionality. For example:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
                        pageLength: 10,
                        filter: true
                        deferRender:    true,
                        scrollY:        200,
                        scrollCollapse: true,
                        scroller:       true
                    });
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working as well when trying to  search anything from the search bar it displays No matching records found even if its there

Comment: The same code is working perfectly in VScode but not working in Eclipse

Comment: Oh! That's strange